# Check if phone received bluetooth file android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I know how to connect 2 android phones (in code). I know how to programmatically let the user send files via Bluetooth. But is there a way for the an app to check if the phone received a file?

The code I use to send a file is the following:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
Uri fileUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), selectedImage);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "SHARE TO"));
```